# If the web service A is down, how can you make the osb business service point to web service B

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, soa, osb

If the web service A is down, how can you make the osb business service point to web service B.

This is like a back up web service.

So, try invoking web service A, but if it is unavailable invoke web service B.

Comment: Load balancing, clustering and calling the other service on exception comes to mind.

Comment: As for the people marking down the question, please at least give a reason in the comments. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSB supports multiple endpoint URLS with load balancing algorithm, and you can provide retry count there so in case if the service is not available on one endpoint then it will be tried to second endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to handle it with Stage (or Route) Error Handler in the Proxy Service

If it is truly the same Business Service (same WSDL), then look at the Load Balancing Algorithm and the Endpoint URI list on the Business Service properties.